# Why does not change the sending credentials of the email in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to dynamically change the sender of the email through config but it doesn't work, it always sends from the email configured in the .env.

```
$config = array(
    'driver'     => 'smtp',
    'host'       => 'smtp.googlemail.com',
    'port'       => '465',
    'from'       => array('address' => optional($model->account)->email, 
          'name' =>  optional($model->account)->from),
    'encryption' =>'ssl',
    'username'   => optional($model->account)->email,
    'password'   => optional($model->account)->password,

);
Config::set('mail', $config);

Mail::to($customer_email)->send(new DinamicMail());
```

How can I achieve to send the mail of an account dynamically.

Comment: i don't exactly remember, but one day I had done it with swiftmailer, try a bit search about it you will get the idea.

Comment: Is the mail set to queue by default, is the `DinamicMail` implement the `ShouldQueue` interface? The config change is not saved with the queue.

Comment: DynamicMail is a simple class that extends Mailable

Answer (score 0):

**This was the code I had used for multiple emails**

```
// Backup your default mailer
   $backup = Mail::getSwiftMailer();

// Setup your gmail or other mailer
   $transport = (new \Swift_SmtpTransport(env('MAIL_HOST'), env('MAIL_PORT'), env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION')))
               ->setUsername(env('MAIL2_USERNAME'))
               ->setPassword(env('MAIL2_PASSWORD'));
// Any other mailer configuration stuff needed...

   $custom_mail = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);

// Set the mailer
   Mail::setSwiftMailer($custom_mail);

// Send your message
   Mail::to('test@test.com')->send(new InsuranceMail( (object)$mail_data) );
// Mail::to(config('mail.insurance'))->send(new InsuranceMail( (object)$mail_data) );

// Restore your original mailer
   Mail::setSwiftMailer($backup);
```

*Note: `MAIL2_USERNAME` or `MAIL_HOST` are also added in `.env`, the rest I think you get the idea*